# Add "+" in place of space in php

Tags: php, string

I would like to add + sign where ever I find space in string.

I have something like

```
 $str = "How are   you.? I'm    fine."
```

should be

```
 $C_str = "How+are+you.?+I'm+fine."
```

How I can do this in php.?
Any better idea.?

Comment: Questions asking for code should **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: `preg_replace('/\s+/', '+', $str);`

Comment: If you're trying to URL-encode the string, use the function [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode). In any case, this sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is just single space between chars use

```
$C_str = str_replace(' ','+',$str);
```

or if there can be more that just space like tab,etc then use this one

```
$C_str = preg_replace( '/\s+/','+', $str);
```